# Show icon on next empty line in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'd like to show an arrow icon beside the next line for data entry in a tracker I'm working on. In this example, if row 6 is the next line to add information (text) in cells C6 to H6, show an arrow in B6. Once there is text in C6, B6 should be blank and an arrow show in B7 (B8 through would also be blank at this point). This is what I have in B6 but the arrow remains even after entering text in C6 and the subsequent B cells with this formula also have arrows:

=IF(AND(C5<>"",C7<>""),"","▶")

I'd like an arrow only in one B cell at a time, please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the one above and the one beside:

```
=IF(AND(C1<>"",C2=""),"▶","")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! I just didn't think to test the cell beside...thankfully it's Friday and my brain can rest over the weekend :).

Comment: If this worked, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: My bad, I tried to upvote it but can't as I'm new. Didn't see that checkmark. Checked!